# Finding the winner, losers and tied players, based on score

Tags: java

Given a list of players, I'm trying to determine which player has the highest score (the winner), which players tied (if any) and then deduce that the remained of the players are the losers of a game.

I've tried implementing a player comparator to sort each of the players by score from highest to lowest. This much will work for finding the winner and losers, sure. But I'm lost on where to go from here.

My first thought was to iterate over the list of players and do some kind of bubble sort algorithm, but I honestly don't know. I was also contemplating some recursive function.

Here's what I've got so far in my endGame() function:

```java
    private void endGame(){
        this.gameRunning = false;
        List<WAMPlayer> scoreTable = new ArrayList<>(this.players.keySet());
        WAMPlayer winner;
        List<WAMPlayer> tiedPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<WAMPlayer> losers = new ArrayList<>();
        scoreTable.sort(new PlayerScoreComparator());
        for (int i = 0 ; i < scoreTable.size(); i++){
            if (i == scoreTable.size() - 1){
                losers.add(scoreTable.get(i));
                break;
            }

            if (scoreTable.get(i).getScore() == scoreTable.get(i + 1).getScore()){
                for (int j = i + 1; j < scoreTable.size(); j++){

                }
            }
            /*
            Need to set the winner and tied players somewhere here...

             */
        }
    }
```

Here are two examples of what output would be like given a list of players: Player1, Player2, Player3 and Player4. The players are sorted by score.

EXAMPLE ONE: 
Player1: 5, Player2: 4, Player3: 4, Player4: 3

WINNER: Player1
TIED: Player2, Player3
LOSER: Player4

EXAMPLE TWO:
Player1: 5, Player2: 5, Player3: 5, Player4: 2
WINNER: null
TIED: Player1, Player2, Player3
LOSER: Player4

(sorry player4)

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`Collectors#groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) and streams to sort each player into groups of scores.

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Player>> mappedScores = set.stream().collect(
                                              Collectors.groupingBy(Player::getScore,
                                              LinkedHashMap::new, //preserve order
                                              Collectors.toList()));
```

Each score value will have its own key and a list value of players who have that score. In the case of ties, the list value of that key will contain more than `1` player.

We can then use a simple for loop to enumerate over the map and determine which players are in which position and which players have tied. This assumes that a higher score yields a lower position.

```
int position = 1; // Keep track of each player's position
for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Player>> entry : mappedScores.entrySet())
{
  if(entry.getValue().size() > 1) // More than one player has this score, so tie
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().size() + " players tied for position " + position);
  else // Only one player has this score
    System.out.println(entry.getValue().get(0).getName() + " achieved position " + position);
  position++; // To the next position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably look at grouping the players by score and then ordering the resulting stream by score. First would either be winner or tied (based on `size()`). Last would be loser (or tied, again based on `size()`.

Have a look at Collectors.groupingBy https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-
and Stream.sorted() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-